# select a tag and change its text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My DOM structure is like below.

```
<div class="selectricWrapper">
  <div class="selectricHideSelect">
    <select name="ageGroup" id="ageGroup">
       <option value="-1">Any</option>
       <option value="0 To 1">0 To 1</option>
       <option value="1 To 2">1 To 2</option>
       <option value="2 To 3">2 To 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selectric">
    <p class="label">Any</p>
    <b class="button">▾</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can select class "selectric" from selector

```
$("#ageGroup").parent().next()
```

but how to select (selector) & change text of its child `<p>` tag, i don't want to change/rewrite `.button` div

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only change the label text, you need to do this:

```
$("#ageGroup").parent().next().children("p.label").text("New text");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ageGroup").parent().next().children("p").text("New text");
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar
Your comment was really help full and 100% correct but i am unable to select multiple answer,

Comment: Because @Russell Bevan was more reliable as he specify class of p tag too, so that it would be change text of all p tags inside it.
again thanks my dear

Comment: The question didn't say anything about the class, it just said to change the text of the `<p>` child.

Comment: Sorry dear,
That's why i said your answer is 100% correct, much appreciated and thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the .text() method:

```
$('.selectric p.label').text('new text here');
```

or:

```
$('.selectric p:first-child').text('new text here');
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: you are right but i need to select p tag starting from '#ageGroup' not '.Selectric' because i got option of '#ageGroup' based on which i need to traverse to 'p' tag, I have multiple '.Selectric' in same page

Answer (score 1):

In this below scenario, we are going to required DOM object from top DIV.

```
$('.selectricWrapper .selectric p.label').text('Place you text');
```

Comment: thanks @Rahul Sambari
Your comment was really help full.